# Shortcuts for QGIS python console commands

Tags: qgis, qgis-python-console, shortcuts

I would like to define a shortcut for *"Save"* in the python console, is there a way to achieve that ?

Is it possible to define shortcuts **only for the given context of the python console** and make them available (for other tasks) in other contexts when console is closed (or ... inactive ?) ...

Comment: What do you want to save? In the console text editor the usual keyboard shortcuts are working... **Ctrl + S** for saving the script, for example....

Comment: **Ctrl + S** is not working **in the python console** of QGIS as far as i tested ... QGIS 3.4. My aim is to save modified scripts.